# In JS what does apparently setting an object literal definition equal to something do? "const {utils: Cu} = Components;"

Tags: javascript

This is the first line from a [js code modules demonstration](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9045387) that I don't understand. What exactly is the first line doing?

```
const {utils: Cu} = Components;
const chromeModulesPath = 'chrome://bootstrap-jsm/content/';
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
//Cu.import(chromeModulesPath + '/helloWorld.jsm'); //we CANNOT import it here we must do it in startup otherwise we get this error:
```

Comment: **{utils: Cu}** is not an object. It's called **DESTRUCTURING OPERATOR** . Refer  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When **destructuring** an object in JavaScript, you also have the option of **renaming** the extracted variables using the syntax above.

For example, take a look at this code:

```js
const {fruits: apples} = {fruits: 10};
console.log(apples); // prints 10
```

In the example above, we are taking the variable **fruits** from the object and naming it **apples** in the current scope.

Further reading: [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 1):

**{utils: Cu}** is not an object. It's called **DESTRUCTURING ASSIGNMENT** . Refer  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment for more details

Comment: It's not an operator. It's just language syntax for destructuring assignment.

Comment: @rockstar Updated the answer. Hope it's fine now :)